# How to update only 2 columns of table and save as new record?

Tags: c#, sql, t-sql

Assume I have SQL Database Table as Customer and columns of (it has primery key ID)table are like VisitDate,Company,CompanyRepresentative,City,Phone,E-mail,VisitNotes,Stuation(Lost,Signed etc.),VisitTime(1-2-3..)

I would like to update only VisitNotes and Stuation columns and save record as new row. So it should give me other fields same but VisitNotes and Stuation changed.

Please see below;

```
enter`  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Session["ID"].ToString()))
            {

                SqlCommand cmdUpdate = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Customer_list SET Company=@Company,VisitDate=@VisitDate,Stuation=@Stuation,VisitNotes=@VisitNotes,City=@City,Phone=@Phone,Email=@Email,VisitTime=@VisitTime, WHERE ID='" + Session["ID"].ToString() + "'", connBizim);
                cmdUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VisitDate", Convert.ToDateTime(txtDate.Text));
                cmdUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Company", txtCompany.Text);

                cmdUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Phone", txtPhone.Text);
                cmdUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Stuation", DpStuation.Text);
                cmdUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EMAIL", txtEmail.Text);

                cmdUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VisitNotes", txtVisitNotes.Text);
                cmdUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@City", txtCity.Text);
                cmdUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VisitTime", Convert.ToInt32(txtVisitTime.Text) + 1);                  
                conn.Open();
                cmdUpdate.ExecuteNonQuery();
                conn.Close();
                Session["ID"] = "";

            }
            else
            {
                SqlCommand cmdinsert = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Customer_list SET Company=@Company,VisitDate=@VisitDate,Stuation=@Stuation,VisitNotes=@VisitNotes,City=@City,Phone=@Phone,Email=@Email,VisitTime=@VisitTime, WHERE ID='" + Session["ID"].ToString() + "'", connBizim);
                cmdinsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VisitDate", Convert.ToDateTime(txtDate.Text));
                cmdinsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Company", txtCompany.Text);

                cmdinsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Phone", txtPhone.Text);
                cmdinsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Stuation", DpStuation.Text);
                cmdinsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EMAIL", txtEmail.Text);

                cmdinsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VisitNotes", txtVisitNotes.Text);
                cmdinsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@City", txtCity.Text);
                cmdinsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VisitTime", Convert.ToInt32(txtVisitTime.Text)); 
                conn.Open();
                cmdinsert.ExecuteNonQuery();
                conn.Close();
                Session["ID"] = "";
                Response.Redirect("Customer_List.aspx");
            }`
```

Comment: Tables have _columns_, not fields.

Comment: standing ovation , very helpful

Comment: A field in SQL is something else, either a part of a date/time value, or a part of a record.

Comment: @HbHb try to add the code which you tried to achieve the results, It would help the readers understand problem and provide the solutions easly.

Comment: @HbHb this was a helpful comment. It will be of assistance to you in the future questions and in general

Comment: Make it easy to assist you: [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with `INSERT INTO SELECT`.

I have prepared a small demo for you. It is not for your example but it will help you to see how. You now need to adjust it to your specific example.

[Here is a demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e204990baaebc7a938ac08c60c5f2471)

For table:

```
create table Customer  (ID int, name varchar(10), VisitNotes  int, Stuation  int)
```

It would be like:

```
insert into Customer
select distinct id, name, 5, 6
from customer
where id = 1;
```

Comment: for do INSERT INTO SELECT shouldnt I need two different tables?

Answer (score 0):

Change VisitDate and Stuation while selecting from table:

```
insert into test 
select 'NewVisitDate' as VisitDate ,Company,CompanyRepresentative,City,Phone,E-mail,
VisitNotes,'NewStuation' as Stuation  
from test;
```